# Generate photo SlideShow in Java and Export as Video

Tags: java, ffmpeg, jmf, multimedia

I want to create a cross platform SlideShow maker desktop-application (mainly Windows & Mac), the SlideShow will be generated using a set of images with background music, subtitles/captions and there will be a transition between each slide/image.

I have done all the UI in swing and it all works superb on Windows & Mac. Now the only "little" problem is

> How to **generate** a **video from a set of images with "transitions" & "subtitles" in java** using native java libs/frameworks and add some music in background ;-)

I want the video output format to be at least in avi & mov, with transitions like:
1) fade
2) Zoom (images will zoom-in from e.g. 64x64 to full video size)
3) Multiple (multiple images will appear in single slide)

I have used JMF example to generate .mov from .jpeg images it was buggy but may work if I can add transitions?? But it appears JMF is mainly for media playback it only supports a few media formats (for output).
I have also read a few docs of jffmpeg but it appears it too does not support transitions.
I have also tried FMJ but no use, now I am stuck and need assistance, on how this task can be done in java.

I would be immensely thankful if anyone can guide me in right direction.

--
many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this task with xuggler. Check it out. It might fit you needs.
[Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/)

Comment: Thats a good solution, but xuggler relies on native OS libraries I was looking for a native java solution. Besides I have started working in .net as videos produced by xuggler were not working well on all media players and I didn't had time left to figure out the xuggler. Thanks anyways;-)